# Dropdown list filled using jquery ajax not showing after submit button click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im using jquery ajax to fill the dropdownlist.Every thing works fine,but when i click the submit button, the filled dropdownlist gets cleared and nothing is showing.

What could be the problem ?

The code i've written is given below

```
 $("#locationList").change(function () {
             FillCashSafe();
         })

 function FillCashSafe() {
         $("#CashSafeLists").empty();
         var locationNo = document.getElementById('<%=locationList.ClientID%>').value;               
         $.ajax({
             url: "HealthReport.aspx/GetCashsafes",
             data: '{Location: "' + locationNo+ '"}',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {
                 var optionhtml = '<option value="-1">Select One</option>';                     
                 if (data) {                        
                     $("#CashSafeLists").append(optionhtml)
                     $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
                     $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                         $("#CashSafeLists").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CashsafeId).html(value.CashsafeSerialNo));
                         $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
                     });                         
                 }
                 else {                        
                     $("#CashSafeLists").append(optionhtml)
                     $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
                 }                     
             },
             error: function (result) {                    
                 $("#CashSafeLists").append($("<option></option>").val("-1").html("Select one"));
                 $("#CashSafeLists").trigger("liszt:updated");
             }
         });
```

The button click is as follows

```
<input type="submit" id="Submit1" name="btnSearch" value="Search"
class="btn btn-primary btn-Addbutton " style="margin-left: 4px;" runat="server"   
onserverclick="SearchButtonClicked"  />
```

Comment: Your page is refreshing after the form is submitted, cleaning out the options you added to the list. You have to make sure the list is built on every page load.

Comment: Are you calling a server function with the button click?  Doing a postback?

Comment: If you are Using Update Panel then,
Dropdown named "CashSafeLists" must be out side the Updatepanel
or you should manually call Change event each time like 
<script>
at the end of page
$(function(){
$("#locationList").change(function () {
        FillCashSafe();
    }).change();
});
</script>

Comment: There is no update panel used

Comment: @Dean.DePue Server function is called on button click

Comment: I think Cory has the right answer...

Comment: yes..he was absolutely right ...:)

Answer (score 1):

Your page is refreshing after the form is submitted, cleaning out the options you added to the list. You have to make sure the list is built on every page load.

One easy trick to make that happen is to trigger the `change` event on the list after the DOM is ready and you've assigned the handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("#locationList").change(function () {
        FillCashSafe();
    }).change(); // <-- added this!
});
```

Comment: Thankyou you was absolutely right.But i've one doubt how can i maintain the currently selected item in the cashsafelist dropdown

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you need to access the selected value of dropdown using `Request.Form` name value collection. Assuming your dropdown has a `ID`of `dropdown1` and you are using asp.net webforms. Then you can access using the following method.

```
string value = Request.Form[dropdown1.UniqueID];
```